# How can I change colors of JScrollPane content?

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

I would like to make JScrollPane with changed colors of text, background in the text box and own font, but my implementation doesn't work - I've seen default form of JScrollPane (white background, standard black font). Could anyone tell me why it doesn't work and how to fix it?

```html
public class TextField extends JFrame
{
 public TextField()
 {
  JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(new JTextArea(15, 45));
  scroll.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 300));
  scroll.getViewport().setBackground(Color.BLUE);
  scroll.getViewport().setForeground(Color.YELLOW);
  
  Font font = new Font("Dialog", Font.BOLD + Font.ITALIC, 14);
  scroll.getViewport().setFont(font);
  add(scroll);
  pack();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The actual view `Component` you want to customize is obtained with `scroll.getViewport().getView()` , not `scroll.getViewport()` .

```
public class TextField extends JFrame
{
    public TextField()
    {
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(new JTextArea(15, 45));
        scroll.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 300));
        scroll.getViewport().getView().setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        scroll.getViewport().getView().setForeground(Color.YELLOW);

        Font font = new Font("Dialog", Font.BOLD + Font.ITALIC, 14);
        scroll.getViewport().getView().setFont(font);
        add(scroll);
        pack();
    }
}
```